# Serialize specific property of object's property/field with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

Suppose I have these two classes `Book`

```
public class Book
{
    [JsonProperty("author")]
    [---> annotation <---]
    public Person Author { get; }

    [JsonProperty("issueNo")]
    public int IssueNumber { get; }

    [JsonProperty("released")]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; }

   // other properties
}
```

and `Person`

```
public class Person
{
    public long Id { get; }

    public string Name { get; }

    public string Country { get; }

   // other properties
}
```

I want to serialize `Book` class to **JSON**, but instead of property `Author` serialized as whole `Person` class I only need Person's `Name` to be in JSON, so it should look like this:

```
{
    "author": "Charles Dickens",
    "issueNo": 5,
    "released": "15.07.2003T00:00:00",
    // other properties
}
```

I know about two options how to achieve this:

1. To define another property in `Book` class called `AuthorName` and serialize only that property.
2. To create custom `JsonConverter` where to specify only specific property.

Both options above seem as an unnecessary overhead to me so I would like to ask if there is any easier/shorter way how to specify property of `Person` object to be serialized (e.g. annotation)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could add another property of `string` type in getter of which you return `Author.Name` and in the setter create `Person` (using name given). Serialize that property instead (attribute it with `JsonProperty("author")`).

Comment: You could derive `Book` from `Person` and try `public string Author { get { return this.Name; } }` maybe? *Edit: Nvm, you don't want to serialize whole `Person` class anyways. Not deleting comment for sake of transparency :)

Comment: @Sinatr Thanks, that option crossed my mind but I want to avoid creating another single-purpose property because of that :P

Answer (score 2):

Serialize `string` instead of serializing `Person` using another property:

```
public class Book
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Person Author { get; private set; } // we need setter to deserialize

    [JsonProperty("author")]
    private string AuthorName // can be private
    {
        get { return Author?.Name; } // null check
        set { Author = new Author { Name = value }; }
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you provide a setter for AuthorName?

Comment: @oldbam, for deserializer: `author` value is read from json as `string`, but we need `Author` (another property) value as `Person`. This is what setter of `AuthorName` is doing - constructing `Person` from `string` and assigning it to `Author` property.