# Now to serialise property of my custom class type as string?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I tried to implement GetObjectData from ISerializable, but I couldn't get it working - it always serialises CData as object.

Classes:

```
public class CData : IXmlSerializable, ISerializable
{
    private string m_value;

    //...

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return m_value;
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("", m_value);
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public CData CData { get; set; } 
}
```

Code:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass { CData = "asd"};
string o = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myClass); // returns {"CData":{"":"asd"}}, but want it to be {"CData":"asd"}
```

**Update.**
I am looking for solution where I can avoid changing **MyClass**, because I have hundreds of CData usages and this looks more like a hack rather than proper solution.

Custom converter looks like the way to go, however you will have to remember to use this custom converter when dealing with classes that has CData properties. I am hoping that there should be a simpler and nicer way of doing that (e.g. I tried to set empty string in info.AddValue("", m_value) or possible there is another interface)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serialize specific property of object's property/field with JSON.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38852500/serialize-specific-property-of-objects-property-field-with-json-net)

Comment: @DmitryEgorov it is a bit similar, however I want to achieve this by just telling JsonConvert that I want all properties of CData class to be serialised as a string (using it's private field value - m_value) because I have hundreds of CData properties and I don't want to make anotehr hundred of duplicated properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at building a custom converter for your type: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

Edit: I don't know of any other interface, and it doesn't look like it's possible with ISerializable. However the JsonConvert can be made pretty flexible. For example:

```
class conv : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(((CData)value).Etc);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new Exception(); // didn't bother
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(CData);
    }
}

class Wrap
{
    public CData Test { get; set; }
}

class CData 
{
    public string Etc { get; set; }
}
```

and then just

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t3, Formatting.Indented, new conv());
```

If you have many types that you want to handle the same way, just make the logic in CanConvert and WriteJson more complicated, maybe even using reflection.

Comment: I am considering to implement custom converter, however I think there should be simpler way, perhaps there is another interface where I could just override GetValue (if GetObjectData always represent object).

Comment: Updated answer with example using JsonConvert. You can also add attributes to the wrapper classes to specify the converter instead of specifying it as a parameter to SerializeObject.

Comment: Looks like this is the only way to go, unfortunately. Thanks.